# Debian migration from i386 to amd64 arch

Tags: linux, debian, migration

I have a Debian Wheezy i386 machine, and I have to migrate all packages to another machine with Wheezy amd64.

I tried to select all packages with `dpkg --get-selections`, but there are many libraries with `*-i386` suffix, and I'm wondering what will happen if I try to install those packages on the other machine, because of its different arch.

Should I remove all the i386 packages from the selections list, or change their suffix to amd64?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/how-to-convert-a-32-bit-x86-debian-based-system-to-64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Packages whose names *contain* `i386`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=i386) will in all likelihood need manual processing. There might be corresponding packages with `amd64` in their name, *e.g.* kernel packages; those would be appropriate in this case. Others won’t have direct equivalents, *e.g.* [`ia32-libs-i386`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ia32-libs-i386), and will have to be handled appropriately using multi-arch (if they’re still necessary).

Packages listed as `:i386` (note the colon) are multiarch-capable packages and should be replaced with their corresponding `:amd64` variant in most cases.